# Insert a Row in a table with calculations depending on Previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The Table I have is as follows

```
Acc_id | Name   |  Status    | value
----------------------------------------
  101  |  com   |  Active    |  1
  202  |  net   |  Active    |  2
  202  |  net   |  New       |  3
  303  |  com   |  Active    |  1 
  303  |  com   |  New       |  4
  303  |  com   |  Inactive  |  2
  404  |  org   |  Active    |  5
  404  |  org   |  Inactive  |  6
  505  |  gov   |  New       |  2
  505  |  gov   |  Active    |  3
```

The Following code

```
   SELECT
     t1.*
   FROM table1 AS t1
   INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT Acc_id
    FROM table1
    WHERE status IN('Active', 'New')
    GROUP BY Acc_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 2
  ) AS t2 ON t1.Acc_id = t2.Acc_id 
    WHERE t1.status IN('Active', 'New');
```

delivers the bellow table

```
Acc_id | Name   |  Status    | value
----------------------------------------
  202  |  net   |  Active    |  2
  202  |  net   |  New       |  3
  303  |  com   |  Active    |  1 
  303  |  com   |  New       |  4
  505  |  gov   |  New       |  2
  505  |  gov   |  Active    |  3
```

As you see above for the same id from column 'Acc_id' with Column 'Status' only with "New" and "Active" are selected

In Addition I would also like to add a row under the result. The row should consist of a new 'Status' "Existing" and the 'Value' would be the result of (Status "Active's Value" - Status "New's Value") the other should remain the same.

Eg: From the result above

```
| ACC_ID | NAME | STATUS  | VALUE |
|--------|------|-------- |-------|
|    202 |  net | Active  |     2 |
|    202 |  net |    New  |     3 |
|    202 |  net | Existing|    -1 |
|    303 |  com | Active  |     1 |
|    303 |  com |    New  |     4 |
|    303 |  com | Existing|    -3 |
|    505 |  gov |    New  |     2 |
|    505 |  gov | Active  |     3 |
|    505 |  gov | Existing|     1 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the complexity of your current query

```
SELECT active.acc_id,
  active.acc_name,
  'Existing',
  active.value - new.value
INTO table1
FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE status = 'Active') active
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE status = 'New') new
    ON active.acc_id = new.acc_id
```

Comment: @PaulDraper Brilliant :D